# Starting a TCP Client before the Server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have a tcp client application which does the following:

```
self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', self.port))
```

However, I wish to start the client before I start the server. The reason why is that I wish to log what the server outputs exactly when it starts. However the code above will give a socket.error for on connect if the server isnt already started. How should I deal with this situation?

Comment: How can the server output anything if no client is connected?

Comment: you don't tell us the full history. What exactly required? If client do the job, you could do the loop with error handling and infinitely try to connect and in same time collect the log to buffer. when server would be up - push that data to the server, if i understand right

Comment: I can confirm that it's not clear what your question actually is.